# Issue with OCHA fonts in windows 8

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, windows-8, font

I installed  OCHA icons on windows 8,But once that I try to open the styles with arcmap (10.2.2) I have some funny icons, do you have some idea how to fix this bug...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error a few months ago with windows 8.1. I contacted MapAction and they informed me that it was a known issue due to changes in Windows on Microsoft's part.

"Thanks for contacting us. We know this is a problem at the moment when using Windows 8.1. The problem is to do with the windows font that needs to be installed - Microsoft changed something in the fonts between windows 7 and 8. We are looking at solving the problem and hope to have it fixed soon. Great to know that these are being used."

The temporary workaround on my 8.1 machine that I am using is with png images from http://mw1.google.com/crisisresponse/icons/un-ocha/index.html.

Hope this helps for now.

-C